# How to add a foreign key constraint which refers to a primary key of the same table ( self reference)

Tags: mysql

Hello Everyone, 
                   I would like to create a table which has primary key and a foreign key. The foreign key however references the primary key of the same table. I have read online and found out that in order to add this kind of constraint, I first need to drop this constraint, load the data and then user ALTER command to add the constraint. However, this does not seem to to work. 
Here's the query:

```
DROP TABLE employee;
CREATE TABLE employee (
  fname    varchar(15) not null, 
  minit    varchar(1),
  lname    varchar(15) not null,
  ssn      char(9),
  bdate    date,
  address  varchar(50),
  sex      char,
  salary   decimal(10,2),
  superssn char(9),
  dno      integer(4),
  primary key (ssn),
  foreign key (superssn) references employee(ssn),
  foreign key (dno) references department(dnumber)
);
```

and this is how I load the data in the table.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "employee.dat" 
INTO TABLE employee 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY "\"" TERMINATED BY ","
;
```

I would very much appreciate if you can give me a hint on how to accomplish this.

Comment: What is not working? The reason you can't load the data while the constraint is in place is that unless the input rows are ordered such that the parent always already exists when a row is created (which is difficult and unlikely for most data sets) you'll get key violations for non-existent parent rows.  Your `CREATE TABLE` above includes the constraint. Create the table without the FK  constraint, load the data, then add it with `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Michael, I am getting error code 1452. There are values in my foreign key column which are NULL. I am not sure if this might be causing any problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible First Answer: (DIDN'T WORK)**

```
DROP TABLE employee;

CREATE TABLE employee (
  fname    varchar(15) not null, 
  minit    varchar(1),
  lname    varchar(15) not null,
  ssn      char(9),
  bdate    date,
  address  varchar(50),
  sex      char,
  salary   decimal(10,2),
  superssn char(9),
  dno      integer(4),
  primary key (ssn),
  foreign key (dno) references department(dnumber)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "employee.dat" 
INTO TABLE employee 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY "\"" TERMINATED BY ",";

ALTER TABLE employee ADD FOREIGN KEY (superssn) REFERENCES employee(ssn);
```

I set your create table query to set the table engine format to InnoDB which is required if you wish to use foreign keys.

**Possible Second Answer:**

It's important to note that for this set of queries, no data insertion was needed and I was able to run these two queries on my development MySQL Server without generating any errors.  *You'll still need to add your FK for your department table.*

```
CREATE  TABLE `test_schema`.`employees` (
  `fname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  `minit` VARCHAR(1) NULL ,
  `lname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  `ssn` CHAR(9) NOT NULL ,
  `bdate` DATE NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  `sex` CHAR NULL ,
  `salary` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL ,
  `superssn` CHAR(9) NULL ,
  `dno` INT(4) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `test_schema`.`employees` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `superssn`
  FOREIGN KEY (`superssn` )
  REFERENCES `test_schema`.`employees` (`ssn` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `superssn_idx1` (`superssn` ASC) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but what you suggested is exactly what I tried before and I got this error message:Errorcode 1452: Cannot add or update a child row : a foreign key constraint fails. So, I ran your first create table query, then I added the data.But when I wanted to enter the constraint, it gave me the error 1452.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure you had removed the FK relationships from your first CREATE statement.  I will edit my answer so that you can try something else.

Comment: Yes, I did remove the Fk relationship from my original query. I then added it later using ALTER but it did not work. I have not tried your "Possible second Answer". Let me do that. Thanks alot for the help so far

Comment: Good luck, I hope it works.  Also, you'll need to decide what you want your update and delete cascade rules to be for the Foreign Key if my queries work.

Comment: What do you mean by what is the option ?

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo, I meant to say 'What is the *output* of running this query: `show engines;`

Comment: Ok, I finally got to solve this problem. What I did is that I turned off the foreign key constraint using SET FOREIGNKEY == 0; Then I loaded the data and turned it back on. it works.

Comment: Good job.  I should have suggested that earlier as it was one of the solutions I came across.  I found it strange that your server didn't load up my second set of queries yet mine did.  Perhaps it was because we are running different MySQL server versions.  In any case. I'm glad you were able to fix your issue and move on.

Comment: hey i need to text you are you availabe ? i have the same homework but without foreign keys i didn't know how to upload data

Answer (score 0):

I got your question, you are trying to create a database as explained in book by elamsari.

Try to add a constraint " FOREIGN KEY (superssn) REFERENCES company.employee(ssn); "
before adding the data, since adding this constraint won't affect the adding data into table.

However, add the constraint related to dno using ALTER table command Later after adding the data.
Then you won't get error 1452:

I tried this, it works
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

While entering the value of data as null
always use NULL without quotes NOT like "NULL"

this is why you are getting an error because instead of CHAR(9) you are entering a string of char(4)

So use NULL instead of "NULL"